# Is there a difference between $lt/$gt and $ne in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I am just getting started with MongoDB and trying to understand how indexes work. I have a list of items in a collection. Each item has a version that gets incremented. Then, all previous versions (less than current version) get removed (record is not updated so that both versions are available for a while). There is a compound index on item ID and version. For removing, does it make a difference (in terms of performance) whether you use $ne versus $lt?

I would assume no, but I just want to confirm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without knowing the details of the implementation `$lt` can be more efficient than `$ne`. On a B-tree index `$ne` would be two range scans (`$lt` and `$gt`), whereas `$lt` is just one.

But in your case `$lt` seems to be what you want anyway (to find the older versions). If you used `$ne`, you could accidentally also remove *newer* versions that you just assume do not exist, but might actually have been created in the mean-time. Remember that MongoDB does not support transactions or consistent views across documents. Concurrent updates might bite you here.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there's a huge difference. The ["$ne and $nin operators are not selective"](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/indexes/#using-ne-and-nin-in-a-query-is-slow-why), which means that an index will not speed up that part of the query at all. So if you use $ne, then the version part of the compound index will not be used by MongoDB.